# print $_get index name

Tags: php

is it possible to retrieve $_get's index name?
eg. example.php?la=1&lala=2&lalala=3

how to print 'la', 'lala' and 'lalala'?

many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
  echo "index ".$key." has the value ".$value;
}
```

Comment: many thanks to you and everyone else. every bit of info is of big use

Answer (score 5):

```
echo implode(', ', array_keys($_GET));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var_dump( array_keys( $_GET ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(array_keys($_GET) as $key){
   echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php)

```
print_r(array_keys($_GET))
```

or

Use a foreach loop

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $val)
{
   echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if ($_GET["la"]=="1") {
     echo "la";
}
if ($_GET["lala"]=="2") {
     echo "lala";
}
if ($_GET["lalala"]=="3") {
    echo "lalala";
}
?>
```